# Solve can't solve a system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

Why can't you solve the system of equations?

```
A = p1 = f (p2);

B = p2 = f (p1);
```

To find the point of intersection of the equation system, mathematics is left compiling.

```
A = 2^α c (((c/
 p2)^(-1/α) (-x^2 (1 + α) + (c/p2)^(1/α)
    x (1 + 3 α) + α Sqrt[(x^2 (x^2 (1 + α)^2 - 
      2 (c/p2)^(1/α)
        x (1 + α (4 + α)) + (c/p2)^(2/α) (1 + α (6 + α))))/α^2]))/α)^-α
```

and

```
B = 2^α c ((
2 x^2 α + (c/p1)^(2/α) (1 + α) - (c/p1)^(1/α)
  x (1 + α) + α Sqrt[((c/p1)^(1/α) ((c/p1)^(1/α) - 
    x) (4 x^2 α + (c/p1)^(2/α) (1 + α)^2 - (c/p1)^(1/α)
      x (1 + α)^2))/α^2])/(x α))^-α
```

The command to solve the equation

```
Solve[A - p1 == 0 && B - p2 == 0, {p1, p2}]
```

Comment: I would be surprised if `Solve` can find an exact solution to such a complex set of equations.

Comment: what other alternatives could be used?