# Solve does not terminate when I give it my equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have been trying to solve a system of equations, but I am not getting a solution, perhaps it is because of something that I am missing or I don't know what.

Does anyone know how to solve?

$\qquad A = p1 = f(p2)\quad B = p2 = f(p1)$

where

```
A = 2^α c (((c/p2)^(-1/α) (-x^2 (1 + α) + (c/p2)^(1/α) x (1 + 3 α) + α Sqrt[(x^2 (x^2 (1 + α)^2 - 2 (c/p2)^(1/α) x (1 + α (4 + α)) + (c/p2)^(2/α) (1 + α (6 + α))))/α^2]))/α)^-α
```

and

```
B = 2^α c ((2 x^2 α + (c/p1)^(2/α) (1 + α) - (c/p1)^(1/α) x (1 + α) + α Sqrt[((c/p1)^(1/α) ((c/p1)^(1/α) - x) (4 x^2 α + (c/p1)^(2/α) (1 + α)^2 - (c/p1)^(1/α) x (1 + α)^2))/α^2])/(x α))^-α
```

In order to find expressions for `p1` and `p2`, I have tried `Solve`, but when I evaluate my `Solve` expression it never completes

Comment: Is this the same question as https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224111/72682 ?

Comment: It appears you are missing to much  and the question in this form cannot be answered reliably. `A=p1=f(p2)`  is it a definition of `A`?  What is `f`?   Equality is `==` not `=`. What are `a, c, p2, x`?

Comment: That does not go into the configuration, it is only to explain that p1 is in function of p2 and the same for p2 that is in function of p1, A and B, would be p1 and p2 respectively.

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach such things is to start simple, and work your way up. A greatly simplified version of this is:

```
eqn1 = a == (1/b) Sqrt[1/b + c];
eqn2 = b == (1/a) Sqrt[1/a + c];
Solve[{eqn1, eqn2}, {a, b}, Reals]
```

which gives an answer, though it's already a bit complicated. I suggest you figure out what this answer means, and then slowly add terms one at a time until you can no longer get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering, will there be other solution methods different from SOLVE?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with it. Reduce[ ] can often show more detail than Solve. If you put numerical values, then NSolve is even more capable. Also, you can Simplify or FullSimplify. You could try replacing Sqrt with Surd (the positive square root value).

Comment: Thank, I will try to do that.